# Onclick = function() in javascript, showing "uncaught type error"

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do something like below.

I have 5 buttons in my site.the desire is if user press any of the button, it makes an effect of scaling down.the issue is,**i don't want want all of them scale down when i click one of the buttons**,
so i came with this approach, but its showing me an error.so how can achieve this effect?

```js
items = document.querySelectorAll('.tags');
for (var iterator = 0; iterator < items.length; iterator++){
  items[iterator].onclick = function () {    
    items[iterator].style.transform = 'scale(0.9, 0.9)';            
  }
}
```

```html
<button class='tags'>button1</button>
<button class='tags'>button2</button>
<button class='tags'>button3</button>
<button class='tags'>button4</button>
<button class='tags'>button5</button>
```

Comment: just use `this` in your function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `this.style.transform`instead of `this.style.transform`

```js
items = document.querySelectorAll('.tags');
for (var iterator = 0; iterator < items.length; iterator++){
  items[iterator].onclick = function (iterator) {    
    this.style.transform = 'scale(0.9, 0.9)';            
  }
}
```

```html
<button class='tags'>button1</button>
<button class='tags'>button2</button>
<button class='tags'>button3</button>
<button class='tags'>button4</button>
<button class='tags'>button5</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this approach,

```js
function animateInit(event){
  event.target.style.transform = 'scale(0.9, 0.9)'; 
}
```

```html
<button class='tags' onclick="animateInit(event)">button1</button>
<button class='tags' onclick="animateInit(event)">button2</button>
<button class='tags' onclick="animateInit(event)">button3</button>
<button class='tags' onclick="animateInit(event)">button4</button>
<button class='tags' onclick="animateInit(event)">button5</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can not see all your code. The problem must be in the `iterator` declared with `var`. I just changed the `var` for `let` and works fine for me.

```js
items = document.querySelectorAll('.tags');
for (let iterator = 0; iterator < items.length; iterator++){
  items[iterator].onclick = function () {    
    items[iterator].style.transform = 'scale(0.9, 0.9)';            
  }
}
```

```html
<button class='tags'>button1</button>
<button class='tags'>button2</button>
<button class='tags'>button3</button>
<button class='tags'>button4</button>
<button class='tags'>button5</button>
```